# Loading CSV files relative to changelog file

Tags: csv, insert, liquibase

I have the following problem with Liquibase 3.1.1: I would like to apply Liquibase in the following project structure:

```
database
 - v1
   - data
     - example.csv
   - changelog01.xml
   - changelog02.xml
 - v2
   - changelog01.xml
   - changelog02.xml
 - changelog.xml

project
 - moduleA
 - moduleB
   - pom.xml
```

I try to use the Liquibase plugin in moduleB so I added it to the pom.xml. Among others I specified the path to the changelog file in the plugin configuration.
The changelog file is located in the direcory database. For different versions, several subfiles exist that are included by the main changelog file. The subfiles (e.g. changelog01.xml) load data from CSV files.

I'd like to specify the path to the CSV files relative to the changelog file path but the following doesn't work because the CSV file is not found:

```
<loadData tableName="example" file="v1/data/example.csv" encoding="UTF-8" separator=";">
```

Comment: Liquibase should find the file with that path, as long as "database" is in your classpath. How are you running liquibase?

Comment: I'm running liquibase via maven liquibase plugin. The liquibase website says that "all files are resolved from the maven test classpath for the Maven project". Which configuration is necessary for resolving the error "liquibase-maven-plugin:3.1.1:update failed: v1/data/example.csv could not be found -> [Help 1]"?

Comment: I have the same issue. For sqlFile you have the `relativeToChangelogFile` option which allows you to specify where liquibase should look for the file. Not for loadData though. Don't see a reason why not ...

Answer (score 2):

This is solved in the latest version of Liquibase. See also: http://blog.liquibase.org/2014/11/liquibase-3-3-0-released.html

> Improvements
>
> [CORE-549] – relativeToChangelogFile for loadData, loadUpdateData,
>   sqlFile

Mind to update your XML schema location to the 3.3 version:

```
<xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd
               ">
```